# Why while shifting from ProductDetailsActivity to HomeActivity, a toast appears from the LoginActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-toast

Please, help me solve this issue. I have working on this for days.

ProductsDetailActivity

```
            package com.example.spree;
        
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        
        import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;
        import com.example.spree.Models.Products;
        import com.example.spree.Models.Users;
        import com.example.spree.Prevalent.Prevalent;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
        import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
        
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        
        import io.paperdb.Paper;
        
        public class ProductsDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
            private Button addToCart;
            private ImageView productDetailImage;
            private ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
            private TextView productNameDetail, productDescriptionDetail, productPriceDetail;
            private String productID = "";
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_detail);
        
        
        
                productID = getIntent().getStringExtra("pid");
        
        
                productDetailImage = findViewById(R.id.product_image_details);
                productNameDetail = findViewById(R.id.product_name_details);
                productDescriptionDetail = findViewById(R.id.product_description_details);
                productPriceDetail = findViewById(R.id.product_price_details);
                numberButton = findViewById(R.id.elegant_button);
                addToCart = findViewById(R.id.product_cart);
        
        
        
        
        
                
                getProductDetails(productID);
        
                addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
        
                        addToCartList();
                    }
                });
            }
        
            private void addToCartList() {
        
        
                String saveCurrentTime, saveCurrentDate;
        
                Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        
                SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
                saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());
        
                SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:s a");
                saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(callForDate.getTime());
        
        
               final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                       .getReference().child("Cart List");
        
                final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
                cartMap.put("pid", productID);
                cartMap.put("pname", productNameDetail.getText().toString());
                cartMap.put("price", productPriceDetail.getText().toString());
                cartMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
                cartMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                cartMap.put("quantity", numberButton.getNumber());
                cartMap.put("discount", "");
        
        
                cartListRef.child("User View").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                        .child("Products")
                        .child(productID)
                        .updateChildren(cartMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
        
                                    cartListRef.child("Admin View").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                                            .child("Products")
                                            .child(productID)
                                            .updateChildren(cartMap)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                        Toast.makeText(ProductsDetailActivity.this, "Added to cart successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
        
                                                        Intent pIntent = new Intent(ProductsDetailActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        
                                                        startActivity(pIntent);
        
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                }
                                            });
        
                                }
                            }
                        });
        
            }
        
            private void getProductDetails(String productID) {
                DatabaseReference productReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
        
        
                productReference.child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        
                        if (snapshot.exists()){
                            Products products = snapshot.getValue(Products.class);
        
                            productNameDetail.setText(products.getPname());
                            productPriceDetail.setText(products.getPrice());
                            productDescriptionDetail.setText(products.getDescription());
        
                            Picasso.get().load(products.getImage()).into(productDetailImage);
        
                        }
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        
                    }
                });
            }
        
        
        }
```

HomeActivity

```
    package com.example.spree;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.spree.Models.Products;
import com.example.spree.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.example.spree.ViewHolder.ProductViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

    //private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    private DatabaseReference productsRef;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Paper.init(this);

        productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Home");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView userNameTextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
        CircleImageView profileImageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        userNameTextView.setText(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName());

        Picasso.get().load(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
//        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
//                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
//                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
//                .build();
//        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
//        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
//        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
                .setQuery(productsRef, Products.class)
                .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder> productAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Products model) {

                        holder.textProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                        holder.textProductDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
                        holder.textProductPrice.setText("Price TK: " +model.getPrice()+"/-");
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);


                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProductsDetailActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid", model.getPid());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false);
                        ProductViewHolder holder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
                        return holder;
                    }
                };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        productAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

//        if (id == R.id.nav_settings)
//        {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }





    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_cart)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_orders)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_category)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_settings)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_logout)
        {
            Paper.book().destroy();

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

LoginActivity (which was not used at all while moving from ProductsDetailActivity to HomeActivity)

```
        package com.example.spree;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.spree.Models.Users;
    import com.example.spree.Prevalent.Prevalent;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    import com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox;


    import io.paperdb.Paper;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText inputPhoneNumber, inputPassword;
        private Button loginButton;
        private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
        private String parentDBName = "Users";

        private TextView adminLink, notAdminLink;

        private CheckBox checkBoxRememberMe;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            inputPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
            inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);

            loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
            loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

            checkBoxRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_me_chkb);
            Paper.init(this);

            adminLink = findViewById(R.id.admin_panel_link);
            notAdminLink = findViewById(R.id.not_admin_panel_link);

            //onClickListeners

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginUser();
                }
            });


            adminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginButton.setText("Login Admin");
                    adminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    notAdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    parentDBName = "Admins";
                }
            });


            notAdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginButton.setText("Login");
                    notAdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    adminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    parentDBName = "Users";
                }
            });

        }

        private void loginUser() {

            String phone = inputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

             if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please, enter your mobile number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please, enter your password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                 loadingDialog.setTitle("Login Account");
                 loadingDialog.setMessage("Please, wait while we are checking the credentials.");
                 loadingDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                 loadingDialog.show();

                 allowAccessToUser(phone, password);

             }

        }

        private void allowAccessToUser(final String phone, final String password) {



            if(checkBoxRememberMe.isChecked()){
                Paper.book().write(Prevalent.userPhoneKey, phone);
                Paper.book().write(Prevalent.userPassKey, password);

            }

            final DatabaseReference myRef;
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.child(parentDBName).child(phone).exists()){
                        Users userData = snapshot.child(parentDBName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);

                        if(userData.getPhone().equals(phone)){
                            if(userData.getPassword().equals(password)){

                               if(parentDBName.equals("Admins")){
                                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Admin logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   loadingDialog.dismiss();

                                   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                                   startActivity(intent);
                               }

                               else if (parentDBName.equals("Users")) {
                                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   loadingDialog.dismiss();

                                   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                  Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = userData;
                                   startActivity(intent);
                               }
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Account with this "+phone+ " doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

So basically, when add-to-cart button is clicked it takes me to the HomeActivty but before showing the toast message "added to cart successfully" it shows "user logged in successfully" toast twice. Is my app checking whether user is logged in (AGAIN) while moving back to HomeActivity? Please help

Comment: Can you show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Specifically, the minimal bit

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's viewed my question on kept on wondering why? I have found a solution (Yay!). In my LoginActivity I have written:

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...
```

But I should have written instead:

```
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...
```

Because addValueEventListener() keep listening to query or database reference it is attached to. But addListenerForSingleValueEvent() executes onDataChange method immediately and after executing that method once,it stops listening to the reference location it is attached to. Thus, problem has been resolved.

Comment: I was remembering you while reading this XD

Comment: Haha, Oh you revisited this problem? I am so relieved though XD