# Failing to stop LoginActivity from popping up while RETURNING to HomeActivity from AnotherActivity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

LoginActivity takes user to HomeActivity:

```
            package com.example.spree;
        
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
        
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        
        import com.example.spree.Models.Users;
        import com.example.spree.Prevalent.Prevalent;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
        
        import com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox;
        
        
        import io.paperdb.Paper;
        
        public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
        private EditText inputPhoneNumber, inputPassword;
        private Button loginButton;
        private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
        private String parentDBName = "Users";
        
        private TextView adminLink, notAdminLink;
        
        private CheckBox checkBoxRememberMe;
        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        
        inputPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
        inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);
        
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        
        checkBoxRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_me_chkb);
        Paper.init(this);
        
        adminLink = findViewById(R.id.admin_panel_link);
        notAdminLink = findViewById(R.id.not_admin_panel_link);
        
        //onClickListeners
        
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginUser();
        }
        });
        
        
        adminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginButton.setText("Login Admin");
            adminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            notAdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            parentDBName = "Admins";
        }
        });
        
        
        notAdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginButton.setText("Login");
            notAdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            parentDBName = "Users";
        }
        });
        
        }
        
        private void loginUser() {
        
        String phone = inputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please, enter your mobile number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please, enter your password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
        
        loadingDialog.setTitle("Login Account");
        loadingDialog.setMessage("Please, wait while we are checking the credentials.");
        loadingDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        loadingDialog.show();
        
        allowAccessToUser(phone, password);
        
        }
        
        }
        
        private void allowAccessToUser(final String phone, final String password) {
        
        
        
        if(checkBoxRememberMe.isChecked()){
        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.userPhoneKey, phone);
        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.userPassKey, password);
        
        }
        
        final DatabaseReference myRef;
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        
        
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.child(parentDBName).child(phone).exists()){
                Users userData = snapshot.child(parentDBName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);
        
             //   if(userData.getPhone().equals(phone)){
                    if(userData.getPassword().equals(password)){
        
                        if(parentDBName.equals("Admins")){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Admin logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
        
                        else if (parentDBName.equals("Users")) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        
                            Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = userData;
        
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(LoginActivity.this);
                            finish();
        
        
        
                        }
                    }
        
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Account with this "+phone+ " doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
            }
        
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        
        }
        });
        }
        }
```

Another activity called ProductDetailActivity is supposed to take user back to HomeActivity on clicking addToCartBtn. However,  with the commands for button function erased out, app  still takes user to HomeActivity (weird!) while raising a toast from LoginActivity:

A portion of ProductDetailActivity(addToCartButton):

```
  cartList.child("User View").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
            .child("Products").child(productID)
            .updateChildren(cartMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        cartList.child("Admin View").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                                .child("Products").child(productID)
                                .updateChildren(cartMap)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                   


                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Why does my application takes user back to home activity while raising a toast that says "user logged in successfully although the commands for button function in ProductDetailActivity have been erased out?
I've tried uninstalling then reinstalling the app to gain logical (expected) behavior. No success. I've tried rebuilding; again, no success. I've tried using
(1)finish();
(2) intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); and
(3)ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(LoginActivity.this);

Again, no success.

You can check out the full code of related activities from the link provided:
[full codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527999/why-while-shifting-from-productdetailsactivity-to-homeactivity-a-toast-appears)

You may refer to snapshot for clearer understanding of the situation:
[Snapshot of Activity transitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbn48.png)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's viewed my question on kept on wondering why? I have found a solution (Yay!). In my LoginActivity I have written:

```
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...
```

But I should have written instead:

```
 myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...
```

Because addValueEventListener() keep listening to query or database reference it is attached to. But addListenerForSingleValueEvent() executes onDataChange method immediately and after executing that method once,it stops listening to the reference location it is attached to. Thus, problem has been resolved.